# Query not retrieving record

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the below code but it's not inserting into the database the problem is because of the price field, if I put a static number it works but if I put a  variable it doesn't work,

```
$price_woo = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT meta_value FROM par_postmeta 
                             WHERE post_id='$vi' AND meta_key='_regular_price'");
$pricewoo=$price_woo->meta_value;       
$check1 = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT vehicle_id FROM quote WHERE vehicle_id ='$vi'");
$vidc=$check1->vehicle_id;
$check2 = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT ID FROM par_posts WHERE ID = '$vidc'" );
$vidc2=$check2->ID;

if($vidc2 > 0){ 
    $ins1=$wpdb->insert("quote",array(
        "vehicle_id"=>$vi,
        "vehicle_name"=>$vn,
        "name"=>$na,
        "email"=>$em,
        "phone"=>$nu,
        "price"=>$pricewoo,
    ));

$to = $em;
$subject = "Quote for: $vn";
$content = "Dear $nameq,<br> Thank you for using Pick a ride below is the quote for $vehicleq<br> price: $priceq";
$status = wp_mail($to, $subject, $content);
```

Also how do I compare $pricewoo with another $price, if $price doesn't match $pricewoo then update the `$price where vehicle_id=$vi`, I know i could do:

```
if($price_woo !== $price){
    $uq= "UPDATE par_postmeta SET meta_value='$price_woo' 
          WHERE meta_key='stm_genuine_price' AND vehicle_id='$vi'";
    $ru = $wpdb->get_results($uq);
}else{
  //run the rest of the code
}
```

But I don't know if it is right and would work.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: your second question ... post `var_dump($price_woo);` and `var_dump($price);`

Comment: What happening while inserting into the `quote` table with `price` as `$pricewoo` value? Getting error or saving as 0 or null??

Comment: @sietse85, I'm sorry i don't understand, could you maybe  explain abit more?

Comment: please these statements above your IF te see which data those variables contain

Comment: @TamilvananN, unfortunately no error no null or 0 value, it's just not inserting the record

Comment: Have you checked the value of `$pricewoo` variable and data type of `price` field?

Comment: @sietse85, yes they are supposed to contain data but they aren't because it is not getting inserted.

Comment: @TamilvananN, $price has data which is being retrieved/ inserted, $price_woo  isn't inserting and when it sends the mail there is no data. But there is data when I check the database